# angularjs collapse + ng-if doesn't work ng-show works

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I've got a button linked to a UI Bootstrap
Collapse directive if I click on it
the script show a form to reply a comment.
when the form is showed I want to hide the button
but I've got a strange behavior

this doesn't work:

```
<a data-ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" data-ng-if="isCollapsed" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" title="reply comment">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Reply
</a>
```

this work:

```
<a data-ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" data-ng-show="isCollapsed" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" title="reply comment">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Reply
</a>
```

and I don't really know why !

Can you enlighten me, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected because *ng-if* creates **new child** scope and *isCollapsed* property is created in it on the first click. But ng-if itself is looking at the parent scope.

Try using *toggle()* function declared on controller level for *ng-click*

```
$scope.toggle = function () {
    $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed;
};
```

Consider using the rule:

> Treat $scope as **read only** in templates.